# Windows computer with static IP and 169.254 APIPA address

Tags: windows, networking, ipv4

I have a Windows7 Pro computer being used as a server to control our IP cameras.

Recently, it refuses to connect to any of the cameras, even though the cameras themselves are working. I can access the cameras through their own addresses on a web browser on my computer, and can ping them on both my computer and on the server.

I noticed the server can not pull any webpages, not just the cameras. After doing an `ipconfig /all`, I saw the server is reporting two IPv4 addresses, one correct, and one giving the `169.254` APIPA. There is only one network adapter on this server. I assume the network problems with it are being caused by this second address.

How can I remove this address and prevent this from happening in the future?

---

```
IPv4 Address.......... 192.*.*.* <preferred>
Subnet.............    255.*.*.*
Lease obtained.........
Lease Expires..........
Ipv4 Address.......... 169.254.*.*
Subnet..............   255.*.*.*
DHCP server........... 192.*.*.*
DNS server...........  192.*.*.*
```

---

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...00 24 21 f1 c5 6e ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.128.1   192.168.128.11     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
    169.254.40.46  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
    192.168.128.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
   192.168.128.11  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
  192.168.128.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.11    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

---

```
C:\Users\tim>tracert 192.168.127.101

Tracing route to 192.168.127.101 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.128.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.127.101

Trace complete.
```

Comment: The device manager only shows one network controller.  Thank you for taking an interest in my question.

Comment: Try to disable/enable the interface (warning, you'll loose your remote access to the server) and see if the problem goes away. No idea how that address got there in the first place though, As far as I know that shouldn't be the case if DHCP isn't used.

Comment: This is a Windows7 Pro computer being utilized to service the cameras.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that then.

Comment: Post the output of `ipconfig /all`, please. It's unclear what you're saying and that would help a lot.

Comment: Is the server showing two NICs or just two IPv4 addresses on the one NIC?

Comment: It's doubtful that the APIPA address is causing the problem. Are the cameras and the "server" on the same subnet? Post the output of `route print` from the "server" and of a tracert from the "server" to the ip of one of the cameras.

Comment: OK, you can see from the output of route print that your DG is accessible via the 192.168.x.x interface. You can see from the output of tracert that ICMP traffic has no problem getting to the camera from the 192.168.x.x interface via the DG, so the APIPA address is not the problem.